# 6VDC power sources for momentary switch

Tags: batteries, switches, dc, voltage-source

I recently asked [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/332602/integrating-momentary-switch-with-a-raspberry-pi) where I'm trying to wire up [this momentary switch](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-automation-and-safety/A22NZ-BNM-TWA/Z6671-ND/5603700) to my Raspberry Pi 1 Model A such that:

- The switch is normally open; and
- When pushed down: it closes the circuit, lights up and fires a HIGH signal to a GPIO input pin (GPIO 04 in my case); and
- If needed, I can make the GPIO 07 pin an output pin and make it available to help run the light/LED inside the switch, but not sure if that's needed

The answerer to that question called out that I need a 6VDC power source for this button, because the RPi (which provides both 3.3VDC and 5VDC pins) is not enough for this switch.

**I'm wondering what I could use to provide this 6VDC power.** According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes), AA batteries provide around 1.5V each. So I'm wondering if I could use a [battery holder like this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/mpd-memory-protection-devices/BC4AAW/BC4AAW-ND/66733) to use 4 AA batteries (1.5V x 4 = 6VDC) to power my button, or whether that would provide too much or too little voltage/current. **Either way, what is a safe & efficient (energy-wise and financially-speaking!) to power this switch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All mechanical contact switches have a plating material designed for a specific voltage and current.

There are two basic categories:

- <= 2A implies gold plating for microamp circuits so that oxidation leakage is not an issue.
- ">"2A implies silver/copper/paladium/tungsten combinations over nickel or similar

Since this switch is an industrial type rated or 2.5kV we can assume it is the latter > 2A so we must supply a wetting current to burn off contact oxides.  I learnt how to solve this problem  40 yrs ago with power relay contacts that had a sense relay contact that would fail from a reputable source P&B.  Normally you need 10% of rated current occasionally to prevent oxidation build up so the contact arc burns off the oxide.

The solution is to use a tantalum or any low ESR Cap ~0.1 ohm with > 10uF accros the switch between Vdd and logic input with a 100k pull down resistor or whatever is needed to satisfy your logic input. This RC=T time constant needs to be long than the bounce time, which is undefined and may be 20 ~100ms for a large switch.  So choose wisely and test it to verify bounce time and give it 2x margin.

e.g. C>=10uF to Vdd , Rpulldown <100k

Comment: Thanks @Tony (+1) but I'm kind of shocked by your answer...it almost sounds like you're saying that I have to wire up my own power connector in order to deal with the switch that I'm using. I figured that Omron would provide a suitable/compatible 6VDC power supply to work with their own switches...is that not the case?

Comment: Not really they offer LEDs with different R ratings for switching industrial AC voltage or 6Vdc. You on the other hand are using for uC.  The internal 10K is only needed for >=100V I have no idea what you are switching but it appears to be logic level only.

Comment: Hey @Tony what about something like this: https://www.amazon.com/NOCO-G750-UltraSafe-Battery-Charger/dp/B004LX3AS6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1507576605&sr=8-1&keywords=genius+g750+battery+charger would that work? Technically, I need to power **two (2)** of these switches...could I use this charger to power both of them at the same time?

Comment: That does not include a battery.   Using 5V on the Omron 6Vdc option just means the 2~3V LED + R uses less current and may be slightly less brighter.  So you can use 5V in and 5V out and a USB battery that does same. It has all the converters inside. 
 https://www.amazon.com/SKG-Economical-Portable-External-Battery/dp/B00XHSK732/ref=sr_1_64?s=automotive&ie=UTF8&qid=1507579054&sr=1-64&keywords=usb+battery+pack+5v  I believe you are just using it as a big microcurrent switch with indicator LED, so that should work. But you can also consider 6V Gel cell and many other options.

Comment: Thanks @Tony I'll give it some thought. Any safe/known way to wire that USB battery (that you posted the Amazon link to above)? Looks like it just has USB/MicroUSB ports on it...so sounds like I'll be cutting the connectors off, stripping the USB wire and doing some kind of hackery maybe?

Comment: sounds right... for 100mA intelligent chargers need to negotiate but load side no problem.